# How to get user last login datetime as an ISO 8601 compliant date or timestamp?

Tags: macos, last

I'm running zsh (version 5.9 x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) on macOS (Ventura 13.6.3).

I want to figure out if a given user has logged in during last X days. To accomplish this, I want to get the last login datetime of the user or null if there were no logins. I tried to use the [`last`](https://ss64.com/osx/last.html) command to do it. My problem is, when I execute

```shell
last -1 "john_smith"
```

I get this string:

```
john_smith    ttys001    Wed Dec 17 19:19    still logged in
```

I can get `Dec 17` out of this string using `last -1 "john_smith" | awk '{print $4, $5}'`. But this doesn't solve my problem as `Dec 17` doesn't contain year. I don't know if it is **`2023`**-12-17 or **`1971`**-12-17.

Is there any way to force `last` to either produce normal ISO 8601-compliant dates (or timestamps) or at least add years to its standard output so I would have `Dec 17, 2023`? Alternatively, is there any other command I can use instead of `last` to get this data for a given user?

**Update**

I couldn't find a way to get a full login date with `last` on zsh v. 5.9 and ultimately went with another command (finding all folders under `/Users` that were modified more than or equal to 123 days, credit goes to [this article](https://mikesolin.com/2017/03/14/resolving-a-freezing-problem-on-lab-macs/)):

```
find /Users -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -mtime +123d
```

Comment: Investigate "process accounting". Do: `man sa`. The `last` command is for people, not processes.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man last`:

```
-y          Report the year in the session start time.
```

So you can run:

```
last -1y "john_smith"
```

and have the year in the date.

Comment: Unfortunately the `-y` flag for the `last` command is not present in zsh v. 5.9

Comment: @AriLinn I'm also using zsh 5.9. The `last` command is independent from zsh. Upgrading to macOS 14.2 will upgrade the `last` command and solve your issue.